# Angular.js Error: Expected response to contain an array but got an object although isArray is set to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular resource factory, which returns a JSON object and looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('resourceProvider', function ($resource, $http) {
return {
Attribute: $resource('http://localhost:49980/api/Attribute/:id', 
{ id: '@id' }, { query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false } }),     
};
});
```

When I 'query' the resource like this:

```
resourceProvider.Attribute.query(function (data) {
  $scope.variable = data;
});
```

I get: Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object.

This seems really strange to me because I'm setting isArray to false. Furthermore the code is working fine on other pcs. So I would be really thankful if anyone had an idea where the error could come from.

Comment: You can't just assign a method to an Object property, you need to create a function and return it.

Comment: Sorry I think you missunderstood me. I added the code where I query the resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. There was a problem with the db authenication and the error message happend to be a JSON object. So there was actually a JSON object returned instead of an array.

Comment: I have this exact scenario too, however the JSON object _is the expected response_ on server errors. It'd be nice if `$resource` could be configured to handle this without sending errors through Angular's `$log` service. It especially adds noise to our tests, where we intentionally confirm how the error handling is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Question1: Why are you using angulars $resource-service and not $http-service? 
Question2: If you want to use $resource, why you whant to override $resource's default behavior? 
 See [Angular Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#usage_returns)

And im not sure but, do you have a typo in

```
return {
Attribute: $resource('http://localhost:49980/api/Attribute/:id', 
{ id: '@id' }, { query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false } }),     
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you must have overread that there is actually nothing wrong with the code. The project works fine on other pcs. The error occurs only on my computer (after I checked it out from  subversion). So my question was if anyone has a clue where the problem could come from.